# CSS: <a> tags disabled after using pseudo elements

Tags: css, hyperlink, anchor, absolute, pseudo-element

I'm doing a CSS exercise wherein the old BBC's site is to be cloned. The original problem was that the white bottom borders of the #topmenu li's appeared wonky (I included this code in the page below as a comment)

That has been fixed by adding the right red border using pseudo elements. However, the anchor tags have been disabled. I think it's due to the red border's "absolute" position, but I can't get the menu to appear as it should without the absolute position. Now, it looks how I want it, but the top menu links don't work anymore: http://jsbin.com/poginowibe/1/edit?output

Any ideas on how this can get sorted out? Any help would be appreciated.

/* This is the original code when the white bottom borders appeared weird */

```
#topmenudiv li {
    list-style: none;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 14px 15px 11px 15px;
    border-right: 1px solid #990800;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

#topmenudiv li:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 14px 15px 8px 15px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #FFFFFF;
    outline: 0;
}
```

/* This is the code after the wonky appearance is fixed but the  tags were disabled */

```
#topmenudiv li {
    list-style: none;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 14px 15px 11px 15px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

#topmenudiv li:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 14px 15px 8px 15px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #FFFFFF;
    outline: 0;
}

#topmenudiv li::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
    border-right: 1px solid #990800;
}
```

---

With some tweaks to Joerg's code, I was finally able to make it work!

```
#topmenudiv ul {
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding: 0;
}

#topmenudiv li {
    list-style: none;
    height: 38px;
    line-height: 40px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;
}

#topmenudiv li:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #FFFFFF;
    outline: 0;
}

#topmenudiv li a {
    height: 100% !important;
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 40px;
    border-right: 1px solid #990800;
    display: block;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

#topmenudiv li a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Thanks a bunch! :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In the future, please include all relevant code in your post and **don't** just include a link to a code hosting site. Your post should stand alone from any other resource; consider what would happen if that site went down in the future!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the  #topmenudiv li::after from your css and change #topmenudiv li in this way:

```
#topmenudiv li {
    list-style: none;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 14px 15px 11px 15px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    border-right: 1px solid #990800;
}
```

**Update**

Use this code and see the remarks below:

```
#topmenudiv ul {
   height: 40px;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}

#topmenudiv li {
   list-style: none;
   height: 40px;
   float: left;
   border-bottom: 3px solid #FFFFFF;
}

#topmenudiv li:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 3px solid blue;
  outline: 0;
}

#topmenudiv li a {
  height: 40px !important;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 40px;
  border-right: 1px solid #990800;
  display: block;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;

}

#topmenudiv li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Remove all your topmenudiv stuff in CSS, also this one above the comments.

I made the border-bottom line for hovering blue, so you can see that it works.

You are using an image on the right site of the topbar, #sphere. This should be an background-image in CSS, so you have not to handle with z-index and then the rest of the links will work.

What I have done is, give the a tags some height and line-height and bind the red border-left to it. I also removed some paddings and margins.

Comment: Thanks, @Joerg, but then, that will make the wonky appearance of the white bottom border re-appear.

Comment: Could you please post an image? I don't see a white bottom-border.

Comment: The borders below the li's will only appear when you mouse over them. Here is the screenshot. This [ http://prntscr.com/68ohp6 ] shows the code WITH the #topmenudiv li::after attribute. This one [ http://prntscr.com/68oh86 ] shows the code WITHOUT the #topmenudiv li::after attribute.